# Automatically Include wp-load on Admin Plugin View Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress plugin that allows admins to edit store hours from the backend of Wordpress. When a user clicks a department for which to edit the hours, a separate view ('hours.php') loads via jQuery

```
.load()
```

from this view, the list of hours for that department is supposed to be called up and displayed to the user. The functions that complete these tasks are in a separate class file. The problem is that in order for this class to be called I have to include the wp-load.php file as well as the class file. I do not want to do this as my hours.php file looks like this:

```
    include('../../../../wp-load.php');
    include('../class.libhours-database.php');
```

I know that is bad practice and do not intend on keeping it that way.

I read this article [on query_vars and parse_request](https://willnorris.com/2009/06/wordpress-plugin-pet-peeve-2-direct-calls-to-plugin-files) but I don't think this is exactly what I am looking for as I am not passing a URL at any point.

Remember: this plugin is ONLY accessible by admins and is only done on the backend.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is the admin editing hours in something like a modal window created with jQuery or on a normal page in the Admin backend?

Comment: It's a normal page it is just loaded into a <div> via jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress always loads wp-load.php, so you don't have to worry about that.

If your PHP script that handles yor Ajax call from the load() needs a separate class to create the HTML to return, then having it include the necessary PHP file that contains the class is perfectly appropriate.